# WPF MediaElement control plays in debug sessions, but not at runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I'm designing and testing an MP4 viewer control that looks like the image below, a simple list-details kind of layout. Users select an item from the list, and the movie can be played on the right. I'm using the `MediaElement` control from the WPF 4.5.x stack. At debug, this control works beautifully. Outside the debugger the `MediaElement` control does not play back anything. Instead, once the `PlayerMediaElement.Play()` method is called (in code-behind on the details control), the program saturates one CPU core, with 50% of the utilization depicted as system overhead:

[image]

[image: Movie Control]

The XAML for the MediaElement control looks like this:

```
                               <MediaElement 
                                Source="{Binding MovieFile}" 
                                Loaded="PlayerMediaElement_Loaded" 
                                x:Name="PlayerMediaElement" 
                                MediaOpened="Element_MediaOpened" 
                                ScrubbingEnabled="True" 
                                LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Manual"
                                />
```

The binding points to a string containing the full path of the file. "C:\MyMovies\Movie.MP4", that kind of thing.

Code-behind for the control with the `MediaElement` in it contains the code recommended by Microsoft for manual transport control; events and timers, etc. What I can't understand is why it fails to work outside of debugging sessions. The movies simply don't play, and data context switching collapses the `MediaElement` control altogether.

What should I be looking for?

Comment: Doesit work for other computers? In virtual machine?

Comment: I haven't gotten it to work on the development computer. There is little hope that it will work on a test VM.